# How to write regEx to get value .4318. from String app.abc.4318.20161017223456.log.gz in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am using below pattern to get four digit number from below string.

Required output is `.4318.`

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String path = "app.xyz.4318.20161017223456.log.gz";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4})");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(path);
    if (m.find()) {
         System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

Output: `4318` but, I need output like `.4318.`

Please suggest any pattern to get the output as `.4318.`

Comment: `Pattern.compile("(\\.\\d{4}\\.)");`...?

Comment: @Reimeus this is missing the other point.

Comment: any pattern is not suitable solution to the problem, you should clarify what a pattern do you want.

Comment: plz provide other possible **path** so we can understand inputs to give proper regex. else @Reimeus is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("(\\.\\d{4})");
```

"\." is an escaped period.